# Capture voice from a stream and translate it

Tags: audio, automation

I hoped that potentially there is something that will help me do it with just one step, however there might be other steps for it.

The problem is, that there is a game I follow, however all the major informations (devblogs and streams) is passed over mostly in french. Today there is one stream on Twitch that I would love to understand, however French has never crossed my path outside of the game. I was hoping there would be a way for me to launch the stream, capture the text spoken during it and translate it to English.

So far, the best idea that came to my mind would be to open up google translate, turn the volume up and let it speak to itself, however I hoped there would be something that listens to an application/window inside the system without the use of the actual microphone and speaker.

Enjoy your day, all!

Comment: Tool/product/service recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Also, this question, as written, doesn't seem to be about programming (so, more suited for SuperUser). Note: even on SuperUser, this would be considered off-topic, as you're asking a general recommendation question. You'd need to alter your question to be something specific there.

Comment: Also please be mindful of tags. For instance: `[twitch]` is for questions specifically about the Twitch API (e.g. writing a program that interacts with the Twitch service), and `[translation]` is for translating strings (again, specific to programming). I removed these tags, accordingly.